# Django Image not showing up in django when using template tags

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

When i try calling an image like this `{{ profile.image.url }}`  it works in the profile page, but in the home page when i do `{{ post.user.profile.image.url }}` nothing shows up and that is not what i expect. i have also tried checking if the image url work and yes it's working.
NOTE: It working fine as expected in the profile page but in index.html it seems like nothing is showing up.

index.html

```
{% for post in post_items %}
   <a href="{{post.user.profile.image.url}}" class="post__avatar">
       <img src="{{post.user.profile.image.url}}" alt="User Picture">
   </a>
   <a href=""{{ post.user.username }}</a>
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="profile_pciture", null=True)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} - Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Are you trying to define a one-to-one relationship or a one-to-many?

Comment: One-to-one relationship

Comment: Then you should use `OneToOneField` instead of `ForeignKey`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#one-to-one-relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have defined your `Profile` model results in a one-to-many relationship with `User`, so the field to follow the relationship backward would be something like  `post.user.profile_set.objects.all().first().image`.

Since it appears that you want a one-to-one relationship, the `Profile` model should be:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="profile_pciture", null=True)
```

With this, you should be able to follow the relationship backwards with `post.user.profile.image`.

You can find the relevant [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#one-to-one-relationships) here.